# Excel formula to find how many times a values appears in a range that is dynamic by group

Tags: excel

I have a four columns spreadsheet, the first indicates a firm's primary area of operation, the second the secondary area, the third the tertiary, and so on.
The database is shown in the pic below.

[image: sample of database]

I am interested in identifying how many firms operating in the same primary area that have in common at least one other area (secondary, thertiary, etc.).

I do not have a code that gets close to the expected results below.

I am looking for a formula that generates the results:
5 for firms operating in primary area 119
0 for the firm operating in primary area 12, 125 and 126
2 for the firms operating in primary area 123
5 for the firms operating in primary area 128

Comment: Should not areas 12,125 and 126 be 1 not 0?

Answer (score 0):

To use a formula you will need a helper column and two steps:

In E2 put this formula:

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(($A$2:$A$20=A2)*(($B$2:$D$20=B2)+($B$2:$D$20=C2)+($B$2:$D$20=D2)>0)*($B$2:$D$20<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B$2:$D$20)^0))>0))
```

And confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  Then copy the formula down.

[image]

Then you want to list the primary and use MAXIFS to get the max:

```
=MAXIFS(E:E,A:A,H2)
```

Or AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,$E$2:$E$20/($A$2:$A$20=H2),1)
```

[image]